# changing appearance of my website header on navigation to a different page

Tags: php, html, css

Hi i am new to web development. I am making a website of eCommerce. I have different pages in my website. For all pages i have made a header.php file because header remains almost same on different pages. But i want to customize my header in some cases. Like if i go to signin page from my home page then i would want my search bar to hide. how can i do this. do i have to make different header files for all pages or is there any other way too.

```
<?php require_once "header.php";?>
```

now on my signin page i am using my already made header.php file like this as shown in the above line. in my header.php i have my logo ,a search bar , sign in and signup option etc. that is fine for the home page but when i go to the signin page i want search bar as well as sign in and signup options to hide. i have tried this but still not working

```
<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']!="http://localhost/projectt/sign-up.php")    

      { echo '<div id="nav-search">
       <form>
       <table>
       <tr>
       <td>Search</td>
       <td><input type="text" placeholder="search for items" id="textbox" size="15px"/></td>
       <td><button type="submit" id="search" name="search" ></td>
       </tr>
       </table>
       </form>

       </div>
        </div>';
} 
?>
```

Comment: Use php conditions instead... if : else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in two ways:

1. (the one I would choose) Write your customised code for the login
   page and put it directly into the file
2. Write a condition like this into header.php

   ```
   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']!="addressofyourloginpage"){
   //the code you want to hide
           }
   ```

Comment: in the curly braces should i use css to hide those divs of search bar and sign in and sign up options?

Comment: Just put the code you don't want to display in the login page into if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']!="addressofyourloginpage"){
//the code you want to hide
        } , css won't be necessary

Comment: is it like this
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']!="sign-in.php")
{div class="search-bar") etc}

Comment: Exactly! Just remember to put html code using "echo" (like if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']!="sign-in.php") {echo '<div class="search-bar">...';} )

Comment: i have tried this but still these things are not hiding
 `<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']!="http://localhost/projectt/sign-up.php")           
      { echo '<div id="nav-search">
       <form>
       <table>
       <tr>
       <td>Search</td>
       <td><input type="text" placeholder="search for items" id="textbox" size="15px"/></td>
       <td><button type="submit" id="search" name="search" ></td>
       </tr>
       </table>
       </form>
       
       </div>
   
   </div>';}
   ?>`

Comment: Replace "http://localhost/projectt/sign-up.php" with "/projectt/sign-up.php". If it doesn't work, put this code into sign-up.php: echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; and replace "/projectt/sign-up.php" with what is out-put